# Symony: Render a form for each element

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm trying to render an edit form in a modal for each element on the same page I create them, but it seems not possible to render a same form multiple times.

This is my controller:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/outcome", name="outcome")
 */
public function index(OutcomeRepository $repo, Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $manager): Response
{
    $outcomes = $repo->findAll();

    $outcome = new Outcome();
    $form = $this->createForm(OutcomeType::class, $outcome);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $manager->persist($outcome);
        $manager->flush();

        $this->addFlash(
            'success',
            "Income <strong>{$outcome->getTitle()}</strong> has been added."
        );
        return $this->redirectToRoute('outcome');
    }

    return $this->render('outcome/outcome.html.twig', [
        'outcomes' => $outcomes,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

This is the OutcomeType:

```
    class OutcomeType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title', TextType::class, [
                'label' => "Title",
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => "Write a title"
                ]
            ])
            ->add('amount', MoneyType::class, [
                'label' => "Amount",
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => "Write an amount"
                ]
            ])
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, [
                'label' => 'Send',
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'btn btn-primary'
                ]
            ]);
    }
```

And this is the twig part:

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#newOutcomeModal">
  New outcome
</button>

    <div class="modal fade" id="newOutcomeModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="newOutcomeModal" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="newOutcomeModal">Add a new outcome</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    {{form_start(form)}}
                        {{form_widget(form)}}
                    {{form_end(form)}}
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    {% for outcome in outcomes %}
        <div class="card m-4">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{outcome.title}}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">{{outcome.amount}}</p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#editOutcomeModal{{outcome.id}}">Edit</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal fade" id="editOutcomeModal{{outcome.id}}" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="editOutcomeModal{{outcome.id}}" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="editOutcomeModal{{outcome.id}}">Edit {{outcome.title}} outcome</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        {{form_start(form)}}
                            {{form_widget(form)}}
                        {{form_end(form)}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

I get the error: "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Field "outcome" has already been rendered, save the result of previous render call to a variable and output that instead.")."

I don't know how to solve this. I tried to turn the fields of OutcomeType in a collectionType but it didn't work.

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: So finally I was able to render form but not a symfony one. I've made a "regular" form in the twig loop.

Do someone know how I can handle the form to check validations with symfonys constraints ?

Comment: About your validation question: [How to validate arrays](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/raw_values.html). For handling multipe forms you can try [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65862450).